# Report of completed Repeated Tasks in Orgmode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In orgmode, I am able to get the list of tasks completed for the month by having a custom command like

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("rm" "Current Month review"
               agenda ""
               ((org-agenda-span 'month)

                (org-agenda-show-all-dates t)
                (org-agenda-start-with-clockreport-mode t)

                (org-agenda-archives-mode t)
                (org-agenda-start-day "01")
                (org-read-date-prefer-future nil)
                (org-agenda-start-with-log-mode t)
                (org-agenda-overriding-header "Month in Review")
                (org-agenda-skip-function
                 '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'nottodo 'done))
                )))
```

The above command skips the repeated tasks since the current state is "TODO", even though it has a LOGBOOK with dates

. eg

```
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2017-05-07 Sun 20:55]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2017-04-07 Fri 22:42]
:END:
```

Is there any solution to include completed repeated tasks also in the report...

Comment: [Here is a similar question on Emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/16610/675), with only a partial solution at present.